# How to style active navigation link on route in an angular dart project?

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-html

I am trying to implement the border bottom on the active link of the navigation router. But the navigation text gets hidden `<a>Link 1</a>` while click on the menu item.

[image]Have a look at the image attached in the question.

app_component.html

```
<div class="material-content">
    <header class="material-header shadow">
        <div class="material-header-row">
            <material-button class="material-drawer-button" icon (trigger)="drawer.toggle()">
                <material-icon icon="menu"></material-icon>
            </material-button>
            <span class="material-header-title">YOUR TITLE</span>
            <div class="material-spacer"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="border-bottom"></div>
        <div class="header-nav">
            <div class="material-header-row">
                <nav class="material-navigation">
                    <a [routerLink]="RoutePaths.name.toUrl()"
                       [routerLinkActive]="'active'">Link 1</a>
                </nav>
                <nav class="material-navigation">
                    <a>Link 2</a>
                </nav>
                <nav class="material-navigation">
                    <a>Link 3</a>
                </nav>
                <nav class="material-navigation">
                    <a>Link 4</a>
                </nav>
                <nav class="material-navigation">
                    <a>Link 5</a>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <router-outlet [routes]="Routes.all"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

app_component.css

```
.active {
  background: #039be5;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The class that you are providing is changing the WHOLE anchor to be blue background, a height or 2px, and positioned in the bottom left corner. This is probably not what you want.

```
.active {
  background: #039be5;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

You could set the border-bottom itself to have the style. Or add another element for this style and use.

```
.active span  {
  ...
}
```

or

```
.active:after {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.active a {
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
  border-bottom-color: $mat-blue;
  padding-bottom: $mat-grid *2;
}
```